# Add custom customer address attribute in sales order grid collection in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Hi I want to show some custom customer address attribute in sales order grid.

How to achieve that ?

below is my Collection. I have successfully added table fields from another table but unable to add attributes from customer/address

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
                    'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping"',array('sfoa.street', 'sfoa.city','sfoa.company','sfoa.customer_address_id'));


            $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
            ->setIsCustomerMode(true);


    Mage::log($collection);
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Anurag Patbandha

According to your code ,you can only add fields of `sales_flat_order_address`.
If you want to add `customer address attribute to order grid then you need join`  to `customer/address` collection with it  `on default shipping or billing address`